# coremltools convert output to float

Tags: coreml, coremltools

Hey i have model with format .pth, I decided to convert this model to apple .mlmodel by .pth -> .onnx -> .mlmodel

I used coremltools to convert input to image but i need to convert output to Double. now I Have something like MultiArray (Float32) MultiArray of shape (1, 1, 1, 1, 1). The first and second dimensions correspond to sequence and batch size, respectively

I try make something like this

```
import coremltools
from coremltools.proto import FeatureTypes_pb2 as ft


spec = coremltools.utils.load_spec("ios.mlmodel")
output = spec.description.output[0]
output.type = ft.DoubleFeatureType
model.save('testowymodel2.mlmodel')
```

Answer (score 1):

Define this function:

```
import coremltools.proto.FeatureTypes_pb2 as ft

def update_multiarray_to_double(feature):
    if feature.type.HasField("multiArrayType"):
        feature.type.multiArrayType.dataType = ft.ArrayFeatureType.DOUBLE
```

Then call it like so:

```
for feature in spec.description.output:
    update_multiarray_to_double(feature)

coremltools.utils.save_spec(spec, "woot.mlmodel")
```

Comment: Okej, I don't know how to explain this but in python i have only one output like 
`print(r'Score: %.2f' % preds.item())`
and i try get something the same on core ml, i don't need Array  just only one float/double

Comment: In that case you'll get an MLMultiArray with just a single item in it.